# error on uploading of xlsx file retuen 502 error using postman

Tags: python, postman

hi from postman when ever I am trying to upload a xlsx file I am getting 502 error . other then that I am able to upload any kind of file like csv , image , pdf etc . is this a postman configurations issue  ?

[image: my postman configurations look like this]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be number of things, but I think it is one f these two:

1. the `xlsx` file is larger than the other files you've tried and the server does not accept large files (some server will consider 1 MB as large file)
2. the firewall on the server is rejecting all `xlsx` file because it could contain virus or something.

Comment: sir thanks for answer , 1st point xlsx file is only 11.3 kb . and for second point I am using api gateway to upload on s3 .

Comment: @sajjadahmad in that case check out these links [first link](https://blog.postman.com/using-self-signed-certificates-with-postman/)  and   [second link](https://christinavhastenrath.medium.com/testing-file-uploads-to-aws-s3-with-iam-user-credentials-in-postman-5026fbde3ca6)

Comment: sir both checked no issue on my side . is this possible that few extensions we have to enable from aws ?